# Match input .csv to output folder by matching on select input variables python

Tags: python, csv

I am a complete novice with python so any help or pointers is appreciated. I have an input .csv file that looks like this for ~ 500,000 rows of data:

```
dwelling,wall,weather,occ,height,temp
5,2,Ldn,Pen,154.7,23.4
5,4,Ldn,Pen,172.4,28.7
3,4,Ldn,Pen,183.5,21.2
```

For each combination of input variables, there is a folder with 'results' for that combination. I want to route each row of data to its output folder depending on selected input variables using a look up which looks like the following;

```
dwelling,wall,weather,occ,folder
5,2,Ldn,Pen,Semi_detached_solid
5,4,Ldn,Pen,Semi_detached_cavity
3,4,Ldn,Pen,Detached_cavity
```

The following code does this if the continuous variables (height, temp) are removed from the input dataframe, but these variables are needed. Is there a way to ignore the "non-matching" variables when linking each row to its output folder without totally removing them?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# read the lookup file into a pandas dataframe
lookup_df = pd.read_csv('lookup.csv')

# create a dictionary from the dataframe using the input variables as keys and the folder names as values
folder_map = lookup_df.set_index(['dwelling', 'wall', 'weather', 'occ']).to_dict()['folder']

# read the input file, create another dataframe
input_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

for _, row in input_df.iterrows():
    dwelling, wall, weather, occ = row
    folder = folder_map[(dwelling, wall, weather, occ)]
    # navigate to the correct folder
    os.chdir(folder)
    # (insert code here to do whatever you want in the folder)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match input .csv to output folder python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849426/match-input-csv-to-output-folder-python)

Comment: No it doesn’t run with the cont. variables included in the input file

Answer (score 0):

Something like below.

Setup:

```
cat input.csv
dwelling,wall,weather,occ,height,temp
5,2,Ldn,Pen,154.7,23.4
5,4,Ldn,Pen,172.4,28.7
3,4,Ldn,Pen,183.5,21.2
3,4,Ldn,Pen,190.2,30.3


cat lookup.csv
dwelling,wall,weather,occ,folder
5,2,Ldn,Pen,Semi_detached_solid
5,4,Ldn,Pen,Semi_detached_cavity
3,4,Ldn,Pen,Detached_cavity

Code
```

```
import csv

# Make a lookup dict where the key is a tuple of the four values you 
# are interested in: dwelling,wall,weather,occ. And the value is the folder name.
with open('lookup.csv') as lookup_file:
    lookup_dict = {}
    cDr = csv.DictReader(lookup_file)
    for row in cDr:
        lookup_dict.update({(row['dwelling'], row['wall'], row['weather'], row['occ']): row['folder']})


# Use lookup dict to create an input dict that will have a key of the folder name and start with an empty list as value.
# For each row in input file create a tuple of the four values(dwelling,wall,weather,occ) and test if they exist as key in lookup dict.
# If they do append the row to the list for the corresponding folder name.
with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    iDr = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    input_dict = {}
    for val in lookup_dict:
        input_dict.update({lookup_dict[val] : []})
    for row in iDr:
        key_tuple = (row['dwelling'], row['wall'], row['weather'], row['occ'])
        if lookup_dict.get(key_tuple):
            print(row)
            input_dict[lookup_dict[key_tuple]].append(row)

input_dict
{'Semi_detached_solid': [{'dwelling': '5',
   'wall': '2',
   'weather': 'Ldn',
   'occ': 'Pen',
   'height': '154.7',
   'temp': '23.4'}],
 'Semi_detached_cavity': [{'dwelling': '5',
   'wall': '4',
   'weather': 'Ldn',
   'occ': 'Pen',
   'height': '172.4',
   'temp': '28.7'}],
 'Detached_cavity': [{'dwelling': '3',
   'wall': '4',
   'weather': 'Ldn',
   'occ': 'Pen',
   'height': '183.5',
   'temp': '21.2'},
  {'dwelling': '3',
   'wall': '4',
   'weather': 'Ldn',
   'occ': 'Pen',
   'height': '190.2',
   'temp': '30.3'}]}
```

Then you have a `dict` with the records sorted by folder name that you can iterate over when adding to folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting a KeyError when it's trying to pick up 'dwelling' in the first with statement. The second runs without error but obv the look_up_dict doesn't work from the first statement. Also, would the input_dict need to have records for 500,000 records (since there are 500K rows in my input df)?

Comment: I added comments for explanation. There is only one `input_dict` with the folder names as keys and the sorted rows from the input csv as a list of dicts where each dict is a row. You don't have to do this, you could make it a list of lists/tuples. I tend to use dicts to avoid indexing issues when the data structure changes and values are added/deleted/rearranged. Python dicts are pretty efficient storage these days so i would not expect them to be an issue.

Comment: You would need to add the code you ran and the complete error message as update to your question. Why use a dataframe, just read the CSV directly as I show. The dataframe will just add overhead. I would also suggest starting with a smaller dataset until you get the code correct.

Comment: Sorry yeah by input df I mean .csv! And I am using the input.csv and lookup.csv you include in your code before I try the code on the bigger dataset (.csv). I've included the error message hopefully someone can help lol